# Limite de Layout android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Bom dia, eu fiz um Layout para meu ultimo projeto, e agr quero expandir os campos, soq para isso eu quero que o layout não acabe no canto da tela, quero que eu possa deslizar o dedo e abaixar a tela 
Aonde eu faria essa mudança ??
Agradeço desde já pela atenção :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você precisa adicionar o seu layout dentro de um [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html), assim:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <!-- Todo o restante do seu conteúdo -->
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Desse jeito, caso o conteúdo do seu `LinearLayout` não caiba na tela, o próprio Android tratará de tornar a tela deslizável.

***Adendo:***

Vale lembrar, que o ScrollView aceita *APENAS UM* filho direto, ou seja, apenas um layout pode ter o ScrollView como pai direto. No exemplo que eu postei, esse Layout é o LinearLayout.

Para exemplificar, você não pode fazer algo desse tipo no ScrollView:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <!-- Todo o restante do seu conteúdo -->
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```